# How to delete a remote duplicate lowercase branch in git

Tags: git

I have pushed two branches with same name but in different case one is in lowercase and other one is in upper case.
I want to delete lowercase branch at remote.
How can I do this?

E.g.:

```
release-TEST-ABC
release-test-abc
```

I want to delete release-test-abc at remote repository.

Comment: git is not case sensitive - just go ahead.

Comment: i am worried about uppercase branch .. it should not get deleted at remote

Comment: git *is* case sensitive - just go ahead.

Comment: check it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359978/why-has-git-allowed-me-to-create-two-branches-with-the-same-name) this will help you!

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. Even if the answer is included in the answer to a separate question, it is not obvious that it would be found in that thread