Why can't I checkout a remote branch from git?
I have a serious issue with git. My client runs a repository on GitHub. I am working on the main branch and want to checkout a release branch.
The issue: my git-cli can't check this branch out.
I ran:
git branch -a

Result:
* main
  remotes/origin/feature/commander
  remotes/origin/release/0.88
  remotes/origin/release/0.89
  remotes/origin/release/0.89

and so on
So i want to checkout the release-branch 0.89 using several attempts that I found here on StackOverflow and in git-tutorials:
git checkout release/0.89


error: pathspec 'release/0.89' did not match any file(s) known to git

git checkout remotes/release/0.89


error: pathspec 'remotes/release/0.89' did not match any file(s) known to git

I found also something like this, that I usually use to create a new remote branch:
git checkout -b release/0.89 origin/release/0.89

this gives an error:
fatal: 'origin/release/0.89' is not a commit and a branch 'release/0.89' cannot be created from it

I am using git version 2.34.1 on Ubuntu 22.
What do I wrong?

Judging by the commands you showed, you did nothing wrong, the error is unexpected indeed.

It looks to me very weird that git branch -a is listing remotes/origin/release/0.89 twice. This could explain the difficulty you're having. But how that happened is unclear to me.

I would suggest that you must have created remotes/origin/release/0.89, which is now a local branch. In other words, you've been doing Bad Stuff and you have not been candid with us about what Bad Stuff you have been doing.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359978/why-has-git-allowed-me-to-create-two-branches-with-the-same-name (I'm tempted to say that this q. is a duplicate).

Okay, so first, it looks like you've wrongly created a local branch with the name remotes/origin/release/0.89. So your first move should be to delete it:
git branch -D remotes/origin/release/0.89

If that works, then git branch -a will only list one remotes/origin/release/0.89.
In that case, you can now do this correctly, which is to say:
git switch release/0.89

That will create a local branch, release/0.89, based off of the remote release/0.89 (and Git will tell you so).

wow, that was a big catch.

It has to include the remote, otherwise git will try to create a local branch with that name from a remote branch that has that name if there is a single remote that has a branch with that name..... so, try this:
git checkout origin/release/0.89

You will end up in detached HEAD state, which is to be expected.

This is just me, but I advise not telling beginners to say git checkout. They should say (to get a detached head) git switch --det And this avoids the confusion where Git thinks that checkout might refer to a file.

Anyway, it seems to me that everybody is failing to grapple with the fact that the very same remote branch is said by Git to occur twice.

Yes you can. Just perform
git checkout origin/<branch>


this gives "did not match any file(s) known to git"
